# nsis 2 can't change mysql password / running sql script

Tags: mysql, passwords, nsis

I have script in SQL:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD("my-new-password") WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And after MySQL installation I would like to execute it. Im trying

```
ExecCmd::exec '"cmd.exe" /C "$instaldir\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot < "C:\passwd.sql"'
```

or

```
StrCpy $sql_file ""C:\passwd.sql"
ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /C "$instaldir\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot < $sql_file'
```

but it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Do you get an error message when you run the command? Can you show this to us?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add cmd.exe, exec and execwait will do.

Try this:

```
ExecCmd::exec '"$instaldir\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot < "C:\\passwd.sql"'
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work!

```
  StrCpy $sql_file "$temp\ampp\passwd.sql"
  ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /C "C:\Program Files\AMPP\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot < $sql_file' $0 ; changes root password
  MessageBox MB_OK $0
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done it
add environment variables path of mysql------u can add from nsis ...use plugin ....else do it manually
at top of the nsis scrip add -->**RequestExecutionLevel** admin for running as system admin
then  for setting a new password add a script -->**nsExec::Exec /TIMEOUT=10000 "mysqladmin -u root password newpassword"**
if u need to change the password ,add --> **nsExec::Exec /TIMEOUT=10000 "mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpassword"**       (neglect 'quotes used for old password)